# Customize jQuery DataTable To Get Custom CheckBox Event Row Wise

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am trying to modify `jQuery DataTable` with a custom **CheckBox** column. My requirement is to add a **CheckBox** with every row of a table and add click event with the respective row check boxes, so whenever I click on the check boxes, it should show the related row details or get the data to the database. I am able to get data with `Ajax` call from database and done with the **CheckBoxes**. I was following this tutorial to make it work and it works fine now:
 
[jQuery DataTable with CheckBoxes](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw) 

This is what I've done so far in the back-end:

```
public JsonResult GetData()
{
   var result = db.Doctors.Select(c => new
   {
      FirstName = c.Firstname,
      LicenseNo = c.LicenseNo
   }).ToList();

   return Json(new { data = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In the front-end:

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/dt/dt-1.10.10,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.6/css/dataTables.checkboxes.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/dt/dt-1.10.10,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/1.2.6/js/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
                type: "get",
                datatype: "json",
                data: {}
            },

            "columnDefs": [
                   {
                       'targets': 0,
                       'checkboxes': {
                           'selectRow': true
                       }
                   }
            ],

            "columns": [
                { "data": "FirstName" },
                { "data": "FirstName" },
                { "data": "LicenseNo" }
            ],

            'select': {
                'style': 'multi'
            },
            'order': [[1, 'asc']]
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <hr><br>
        <form>
            <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>License No</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <hr>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now the issue is how can I add the check box click events in the `jQuery DataTable`. So whenever I click with check boxes, I can retrieve the respective row details.

**N.B**: I've done little R&D on this and checked that the **CheckBox** is given a class named **dt-checkboxes**. It's generated dynamically. Is there any way that I can make it to my requirement like assigning unique ids to the check boxes, bit stuck here. This is how it looks like - Simple enough:

[image: jQuery DataTable]

Comment: Have you tried with `jQuery` loops to iterate over the check boxes?

Comment: You do not need to give an `Id` to that. What is stopping you from using ` dt-checkboxes` css class selector to wireup the click event on the checkbox and make the ajax call ?

Comment: I guess, the **dt-checkboxes** class will be applicable to all the check boxes whenever clicked on a single row @Shyju.

Comment: Yes. But your click happens on only one checkbox and `$(this)` will give you that.

Comment: And the code you shared will not render the the checkbox at all!!!!

Comment: I can render the check boxes @Shyju. But as you have written to use $(this), I believe, I can make it work to add the click event.

Comment: I haven't tried with that @AT-2017. But like to follow the steps.

Comment: I said **the code you shared** is not rendering checkboxes! I just copied and tried ;)

Comment: Did you add all the references of the `JS` and `CSS` files? I've added one file locally and others are shared online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event listeners on the [select](https://datatables.net/reference/event/select) and [deselect](https://datatables.net/reference/event/deselect) events.

```
table.on( 'deselect', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
   //get the row information for the row deselected.
   console.log(dt.row(indexes).data());
});
table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
   //get the row information for the row selected.
   console.log(dt.row(indexes).data());
});
```

The above code snippet will provide you the data for the row that was selected or deselected.

I [forked your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usxwftzL/1/) to demonstrate it.